# click callback with audio and innerHTML together not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, audio, callback, innerhtml

In the below snippet the intended behavior is to click on "Play", then the mp3 gets played and "Play" gets changed to "playing". However in my current browsers (Mozilla, Safari) I get the following: When clicking on "Play" it gets transformed to "playing" but no file is being played. Then, only when clicking on "playing" the file gets played. Why do I have to click two times? When commenting out the line "document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = 'playing';" the file gets immediately played after the first click.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
 <div id="player">Play</div>
 <script>
  audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
  audioEl.setAttribute('src','audioFile.mp3');
  document.getElementById('player').appendChild(audioEl);

  document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('click',function() {
   document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = 'playing';
   audioEl.play();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` replaces all the content of the element, not only the text. After the creation of the `audio` tag, your HTML looks like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="player">Play
        <audio src='audioFile.mp3'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So when you replace the content of the div with `playing` you remove `<audio src='audioFile.mp3'>`.

You have to add an element for the text in the div like this

```
<div id="player">
    <div id="player-text"></div>
</div>
```

and use this javascript

```
audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
audioEl.setAttribute('src','audioFile.mp3');
document.getElementById('player').appendChild(audioEl);

document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('click',function() {
    document.getElementById('player-text').innerHTML = 'playing';
    audioEl.play();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the `.innerHTML` of `#player`, including the  `<audio>` element, at

```
document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = 'playing';
```

You can concatenate a `#text` node at `#player` `.innerHTML` using `.innerHTML += "playing"` or use `.insertAdjacentHTML`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
 <div id="player">Play</div>
 <script>
  audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
  audioEl.setAttribute('src','audioFile.mp3');
  document.getElementById('player').appendChild(audioEl);

  document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('click',function() {
   this.innerHTML += 'playing';
   audioEl.play();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
 <div id="player">Play</div>
 <script>
  audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
  audioEl.setAttribute('src','audioFile.mp3');
  document.getElementById('player').appendChild(audioEl);

  document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('click',function() {
   this.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "playing");
   audioEl.play();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```